# Spring Cloud Data Flow, deploy fails when an app output mapped to two different app input:Could not install AppDeployRequest

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

In Kubernetes SCDF (2.2.0.RELEASE), in a simple stream when an output from an app is mapped to two different app inputs the stream DEPLOY fails with an error message "Could not install AppDeployRequest".

[Example Branched Stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYx5A.jpg)
    and

[Skipper Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDtBG.jpg)

[Issue fix:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNQes.jpg)
On renaming the stream fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on both `2.2.0.RELEASE` and the latest master. It works fine in both cases. Also, you don't need labels for the `log` applications as each of them are part of two different streams.